# EMR: How to integrate Spark with Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

Using a EMR cluster, I created an external Hive table (over 800 millions of rows) that maps to a DynamoDB table. It works well and I can do queries and inserts through hive.

IF I try a query with a condition by the hash_key in Hive, I get the results in seconds. But doing the same query through spark-submit using SparkSQL and enableHiveSupport (accesing Hive) it doesn't finish.It seems that from Spark it's doing a full scan to the table.

I tried several configurations(different hive-site.xml for example) but it doesn't seem to work well from Spark. How should I do it through Spark? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Spark is not a replacement for Hive (or other database on Hadoop). Just saying...

Comment: I'm using Hive through Spark, not like a replacement.

Comment: `SparkSession` with `hiveSupport` doesn't run on Hive. It just enables integration with metastore. Nothing more.

Comment: What should I do to run Hive through Spark then? I don't see why the same query in the same Hive table works in seconds in Hive and it doesnt work Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to use the dynamo connector opensource by AWS. By default it is available on EMR AFAIK.

Syntax to create a table using the DynamoDBStorageHandler class:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_tablename (
    hive_column1_name column1_datatype,
    hive_column2_name column2_datatype
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    "dynamodb.table.name" = "dynamodb_tablename",
    "dynamodb.column.mapping" =
        "hive_column1_name:dynamodb_attribute1_name,hive_column2_name:dynamodb_attribute2_name"
);
```

For any Spark Job, you need to have the followings confs :

```
$ spark-shell --jars /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar
...
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

var jobConf = new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
jobConf.set("dynamodb.input.tableName", "myDynamoDBTable")

jobConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")
jobConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat")

var orders = sc.hadoopRDD(jobConf, classOf[DynamoDBInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[DynamoDBItemWritable])

orders.count()
```

References : 
https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector

Comment: I already tried all of that before trying to connect with hive. I don't see how you can access to the Hive table from Spark and do a query with that second part. You are accessing to the dynamodb table (doing a full scan) not to the Hive table.

Comment: The point here is that you will use AWS dynamodb driver. We can't use hive engine from Spark.

Comment: How do you use AWS dynamodb driver to do a query? Again, with that you are always getting the full table